# KeyError at /app/myRoute/ 'Status' - AJAX Post Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-views

From my view, I am simply returning

```
context = {'message':'Request Accepted'}
return HttpResponse(context)
```

I am calling this view with AJAX call and its returning Http 500
with error message

```
KeyError at /routes/AcceptRequest/
'status'

Request Method: POST
```

when i try to stringify the response in javascript it gives :

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"KeyError at /routes/AcceptRequest/\n'status'\n\nRequest Method: POST\nRequest URL: http://localhost:8000/routes/AcceptRequest/\nDjango Version: 1.4\nPython Executable: /home/subodh/joinwheelsv6/env/bin/python\nPython Version: 2.7.3\nPython Path: ['/home/subodh/joinwheelsv6/env/joinwheels', '/home/subodh/joinwheelsv6/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/home/subodh/joinwheelsv6/env/lib/python2.7', '/home/subodh/joinwheelsv6/env/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home/subodh/joinwheelsv6/env/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/subodh/joinwheelsv6/env/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/subodh/joinwheelsv6/env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/subodh/joinwheelsv6/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/subodh/joinwheelsv6/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages']\nServer time: Thu, 17 Oct 2013 15:48:36 +0530\nInstalled Applications:\n('django.contrib.auth',\n 'django.contrib.contenttypes',\n 'django.contrib.sessions',\n 'django.contrib.sites',\n 'django.contrib.messages',\n 'django.contrib.staticfiles',\n 'django.contrib.admin',\n 'django.contrib.admindocs',\n 'south',\n 'account',\n 'socialaccounts',\n 'routes',\n 'Groups')\nInstalled Middleware:\n('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',\n 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',\n 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',\n 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',\n 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')\n\nTraceback:\nFile \"/home/subodh/joinwheelsv6/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py\" in get_response\n  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)\nFile \"/home/subodh/joinwheelsv6/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py\" in view\n  48.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)\nFile \"/home/subodh/joinwheelsv6/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py\" in dispatch\n  69.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)\nFile \"/home/subodh/joinwheelsv6/env/joinwheels/routes/views.py\" in post\n  1157.         return HttpResponse(response['Status'])\nFile \"/home/subodh/joinwheelsv6/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py\" in __getitem__\n  615.         return self._headers[header.lower()][1]\n\nException Type: KeyError at /routes/AcceptRequest/\nException Value: 'status'\nRequest information:\nGET: No GET data\n\nPOST:\ncsrfmiddlewaretoken = u'Dxm5R7omqawuGtJ2v8AuOGsDXXdTCXCa'\nRequestID = u'7'\n\nFILES: No FILES data\n\nCOOKIES:\ncsrftoken = 'Dxm5R7omqawuGtJ2v8AuOGsDXXdTCXCa'\nsessionid = '139167c44021568cf40311753e0480fc'\n\nMETA:\nwsgi.version = \nwsgi.multiprocess = False\nRUN_MAIN = 'true'\nHTTP_REFERER = 'http://localhost:8000/account/TravelCard/Ride/2059/7/'\nGNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'\nSERVER_PROTOCOL = 'HTTP/1.1'\nSERVER_SOFTWARE = 'WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3'\nSCRIPT_NAME = u''\nLESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'\nREQUEST_METHOD = 'POST'\nLOGNAME = 'subodh'\nUSER = 'subodh'\nHTTP_ORIGIN = 'http://localhost:8000'\nPATH = '/home/subodh/joinwheelsv6/env/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games'\nQUERY_STRING = ''\nGNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL = '/tmp/keyring-KIXbNa'\nPS1 = '(env)\\\\[\\\\e]0;\\\\u@\\\\h: \\\\w\\\\a\\\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\\\u@\\\\h:\\\\w\\\\$ '\nDISPLAY = ':0'\nSSH_AGENT_PID = '2016'\nLANG = 'en_IN'\nTERM = 'xterm'\nSHELL = '/bin/bash'\nXDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'\nXAUTHORITY = '/home/subodh/.Xauthority'\nLANGUAGE = 'en_IN:en'\nSESSION_MANAGER = 'local/dell:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1981,unix/dell:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1981'\nSHLVL = '1'\nMANDATORY_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path'\nwsgi.url_scheme = 'http'\nCOMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE = ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you seem to be doing something else that you haven't explained. From your error, cleaned up slightly:

```
File "/home/subodh/joinwheelsv6/env/joinwheels/routes/views.py" in post
  1157.         return HttpResponse(response['Status'])
```

So you have some code in views.py that is looking for a `Status` field that doesn't exist. Of course, we have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Change the return line:

```
import json
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context))
```

Comment: Not working.. btw same error with HttpResponse(string) also, not only with context.